# Pandas' to_sql() behaviour with a table with primary key

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a Pandas' dataframe in which some of its row are already present in the end table specified in the `to_sql()` function.

If I set `to_sql()`'s `method` parameter to `None` (which is the default), I understand that each row of the dataframe is inserted in the end table using a singular `INSERT`.

My question is, when one row fails because of a `PRIMARY KEY violation`, does the method stop trying to insert the rest of the rows of the dataframe? How does it work?

Comment: See the first comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51545670/11865956), looks like it should error out.